# html newsletter rendering on outlook 2007

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, newsletter, boilerplate

i'm become very frustrated about this stuff

i'm using html email boilerplate framework to build my own one. from some test it's still not well rendered on outlook 2007

here to grab my code http://pastebin.com/nh8R4Lng

screenshots [image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

All your images need `style="display:block;"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it seems like an old fashioned table length/width issue.  Outlook 2007 doesn't handle unset table widths very well.  http://pastebin.com/swXTzT19

I forced a few of the td widths to be 30 and made the border left and right longer and ran some litmus tests.  It looked good to me.

Thanks for using the boilerplate.

Comment: much improved but the border left and right margin still resist! at this point i think it's a specific computer problem. btw, in gmail the class image_fix(display:block) doesn't work. it needs to be added inline. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Yeah, the display: block won't work at all without bringing it inline in Gmail.  Gmail strips out the head of any email doc.  If you tag your images with that helper class and use something like premailer to bring it inline it will work like a charm :).